# WebStorm keyboard shortcuts

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I've just started using WebStorm and was wondering if there is an easy way of porting the IntelliJ shortcuts I use in VS2015 into WebStorm, instead of remapping.

Comment: Thanks @PratikAmbani - ive just found this [article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206332139-How-to-make-WebStorm-keyboard-shortcuts-like-Resharper) and it suggest the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, as of there is no provision of exporting your Visual Studio shortcuts into IntelliJ. But yeah, you can configure your Keyboard shortcuts for WebStorm in IntelliJ.

**Reference:**
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 0):

check this out https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

you can export your keyboard settings by going to tools -> import/export